# Jhipster - microservices deployed on distant servers

Tags: jhipster

In a microservices application, I know how to do when services, gatewat and registry are on the same localhost.
Bu where do I set up urls of the servers where are stored my services, considering that my services are deployed on different servers?

Comment: The magic words are  "Service Discovery". Have a look at http://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/

Comment: thanks for your answer